# How to update list withing viewmodel in view? Passing data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am passing viewmodel to create view where I select few properties from dropdown list and then I create new model in database. The problem is that I have to select a product from dropdown list and after button click add product to list(which is defined in model). You can see the code bellow, I am having the problem of passing id of product as it is always null

SellsViewModel:

```
public class SellsViewModel
    {
        public List<Center> center { get; set; }
        public List<Leader> leader { get; set; }
        public List<Member> member { get; set; }
        public List<Group> group { get; set; }
        public Sell sell { get; set; }
        public Guid productSelection { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Product> product { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Product> selectedProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model Medical.ViewModels.SellsViewModel

@{
    var addproduct = Model.product.Select(product => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = product.Name,
        Value = product.Id.ToString()
    });
}
...
<div class="form-group">
                <div align="right" class="col-md-2">
                    <b>Delivery</b>
                </div>
                <div align="center" class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.productSelection, addproduct, "-- Choose product --")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <a asp-action="AddProducttoSell" method="post" asp-route-id="@Model.productSelection" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AddProducttoSell(Guid id)
        {
            var sProduct = _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            svm.selectedProducts.ToList().Add(sProduct);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
```

Basically, I want that when I choose product in view, I add it to selectedProducts list in viewmodel, and than return it to view. Afterwards, I will submit new model to database.

Comment: asp-route-id="@Model.productSelection" is done before render time and definitely before user selection of ddl.  You put values here in a foreach loop -- like rows.

Answer (score 0):

I got your example to work in Core.

First, I followed this tutorial, making appropriate changes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This is the code, starting with my Model-codeFirst and my ViewModel:

```
namespace SOPassDataViewToController.Models
{
    public class Sell
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SOPassDataViewToController.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class SellsViewModel
    {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public int productSelection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddProducttoSell(SellsViewModel sellsviewmodel)
{
    //put breakpoint here to interrogate sellsviewmodel-productSelection
    var viewModel = PrepViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}

// GET: Sells
// I'm using this method instead of AddProducttoSell
//public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = PrepViewModel();
    //return View(await _context.Sells.ToListAsync());
    return View(viewModel);
}

public SellsViewModel PrepViewModel()
{
    //prepping view model
    //sending view model to view
    SellsViewModel viewModel = new SellsViewModel();
    viewModel.Products = new List<Product>();
    var products = _context.Sells.ToList();
    foreach (Sell product in products)
    {
        var eachProduct = new Product();
        eachProduct.Value = product.ID;
        eachProduct.Text = product.Name;
        viewModel.Products.Add(eachProduct);
    }
    return viewModel;
}
```

Here is my view Index.cshtml:

```
@model SOPassDataViewToController.Models.SellsViewModel
@*need the form tag*@
<form asp-action="AddProducttoSell">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div align="right" class="col-md-2">
            <b>Delivery</b>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="col-md-2">
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.productSelection, addproduct, "-- Choose product --")*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.productSelection, new SelectList(Model.Products, "Value", "Text"))
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @*took out will need to put back asp-route-id="@Model.productSelection"*@
            @*<a asp-action="AddProducttoSell" method="post" asp-route-id="@Model.productSelection" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="AddProducttoSell" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@section scripts
    {
    @*//the natural progression for what you are doing is to change the href not the asp-route-id, because
        //href is what gets rendered.  So you can do the following--and tighten it up--
        //you can also use FormCollection, or even possibly window.location, but the best way from Microsoft's
        //tutorial is to use a model like my previous post*@
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DropDownElement").change(function () {
                $("#PostingElement").attr("href", "/Sells/Edit/" + $("#DropDownElement").val());
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

My Action looks like the following.  I use Edit instead of AddProducttoSell

```
    // GET: Sells/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var sell = await _context.Sells.FindAsync(id);
        if (sell == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(sell);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kblau. However, I find it a little bit confusing. 
From index view I want to open Create form. To create form I pass SellsViewModel as written above. In create form I have fields for different inputs for **sell model**. Besides the input fields, I have dropdown list from which I select product, and when I click "add" button I want to update the table that is also shown in create view and add selected product to sellsviewmodel list of selected products. After I am finished with form I submit form to **sell model** with selectedproducts from viewmodel added to sell.

Comment: My current way of thinking is that I want to have main view with create form, and partial view _create with dropdownlist and table that is updated. I render partial view to view with @html.partial, and try to pass data from controller back to view with return partialview("_Create"). I want to refresh only partial view, while main view stays unchanged. However, my return partialview refreshes the whole page and returns only the _Create view.